# Chart configurations in case of high number of legends

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart, angular2-highcharts

In our project we are using Pie chart. When Series count is less then 10-15, all slices are displayed fine, but as more values are added into the series Chart starts to shrink and Legends also show overflow arrow.

So, we are working on a requirement where top 10 counts will be shown on a Pie Chart with a option to load next set values in the series using some kind of control.

Does Highchart have any inbuilt support for the requirement like this?

Comment: There is no problem in displaying in your pie chart thats the default of  Chart. U just need to paginate the data you get in server and limit it by ten. and use the other fuction of paginate to your controll of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve a wanted result by dynamically changing the series data. To update the series data you can use the `series.update` feature.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n9q324jx/

```
chart.series[0].update({
    data: randomData(i)
})
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#update

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, but I was not able validate it with the demo fiddle. If possible can you please modify it.

Comment: @Dev's could you explain more precisely what is wrong with the above demo? As I understood your requirement - you want to have a pie chart which will show 10 data sets from the general data with possibility to dynamically change it to the next 10 data sets - which actually the above demo shows.

Comment: I got it now, due to resolution issue, I was not able to use the button. It help, Thanks